# Make sure an Object matches a data model

Tags: javascript, data-structures

Imagine I have a data model like so:

```
// Pseudo-code, as I don't know how to achieve this
const Model = {
    name: String.required,
    description: String.optional,
    rank: Number.required,
    // ...
}
```

Basically, that means the Object **must have** a property `name` and it **has to be a `String`**. The property `description` is **optional**, but has to be a `String` if defined. Etc.

Now, let's say I have a bunch of Objects :

```
const obj1 = {
    name: 'Object 1',
    rank: 1,
}
const obj2 = {
    description: 'This is object 2',
    rank: 2,
}
```

In order to save my objects in a NoSQL database (Firebase's Firestore), I'd like to be sure that each `Object` **matches** the `Model`. This would prevent having missing fields for instance.

In my example, `obj1` should pass but `obj2` shouldn't has the propery `name` is missing.

And is there a way to throw in the error message which properties are missing?

Comment: Sure, MongoDB for example supports that natively. A quick google for "JS validation" returns some good libraries that do exactly what you want.

Comment: How is the model constructed? From a form? You should validate before the key values go into the model.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

You can create a simple function that will validate your models based on an Array of required and optional parameters.

**Note**: The below has `required` and `optional` parameters hardcoded within the function, but you can also pass them in with very little effort and change in code. Simply remove the declarations and add them as parameters to the function.

---

### Code

```
function validateModel(obj) {
  let
    // parameters specification
    required = ["name", "rank"],
    optional = ["description"],

    // helper methods
    toObjects = (a, v) => Reflect.has(obj, v) ? (a[v] = obj[v], a) : a,
    grab = (type) => type.reduce(toObjects, {}),
    payload = () => Object.assign(grab(required), grab(optional)),
    notValid = v => !Reflect.has(obj, v);

  //output
  if (required.some(notValid)) return false;
  return payload();
}
```

---

### Working Example:

```js
//setup
let log = (x) => { return console.log(x), log };
const Model={name:"n",description:"d",rank:"r"},Model2={rank:"a"},Model3={rank:"b",name:"b"};

// Validation Method:
function validateModel(obj) {
  let
    // parameters specification
    required = ["name", "rank"],
    optional = ["description"],

    // helper methods
    toObjects = (a, v) => Reflect.has(obj, v) ? (a[v] = obj[v], a) : a,
    grab = (type) => type.reduce(toObjects, {}),
    payload = () => Object.assign(grab(required), grab(optional)),
    notValid = v => !Reflect.has(obj, v);

  //output
  if (required.some(notValid)) return false;
  return payload();
}


// Examples:
log
  (validateModel(Model) || "Invalid Model")
  (validateModel(Model2) || "Invalid Model")
  (validateModel(Model3) || "Invalid Model")
```

---

### Making it Multi-Purpose:

If you create something like a model checker, it would be best to be able to check multiple types of Models with it. The below code creates a constructor that takes an Object full of Structs. Each Struct contains an array of `required` and `optional` parameters.

The `ModelChecker` constructor returns an object with a single method, `validate`. By passing in the object you want to check and the name of the model structure you want to check against, you can determine if a Model is valid.

---

### Working Example:

```js
//setup
let log = (x) => { return console.log(x), log };
const Model={name:"n",description:"d",rank:"r"},Model2={rank:"a"},Model3={rank:"b",name:"b"}, Car={"color":"black", "name": "toyota" }, Car2={"name":"chevy"};

//setup validation structures
const structs = {
  "identity": {
    required: ["name", "rank"],
    optional: ["description"]
  },
  "car": {
    required: ["color"],
    optional: ["name"]
  }
}

// model checker constructor
function ModelChecker(structs) {
  let proto = {
    structs
  };
  
  proto.validate = function validateModel(obj, struct) {
    if (!this.structs[struct]) return false;

    let
      // parameters specification
      required = this.structs[struct].required,
      optional = this.structs[struct].optional,

      // helper methods
      toObjects = (a, v) => Reflect.has(obj, v) ? (a[v] = obj[v], a) : a,
      grab = (type) => type.reduce(toObjects, {}),
      payload = () => Object.assign(grab(required), grab(optional)),
      notValid = v => !Reflect.has(obj, v);

    //output
    if (required.some(notValid)) return false;
    return payload();
  }

  return proto;
}

// Examples:

let mc = ModelChecker(structs);
log
  (mc.validate(Model, "identity") || "Invalid Model")
  (mc.validate(Model2, "identity") || "Invalid Model")
  (mc.validate(Model3, "identity") || "Invalid Model")
  (mc.validate(Car, "car") || "Invalid Model")
  (mc.validate(Car2, "car") || "Invalid Model")
```